# Is DECLARE_DYNAMIC required on abstract base classes in MFC?

Tags: c++, templates, mfc

I have a base class that is derived from an MFC CView class and a templated class, something like;

```
template<class TYPE>
class CMytViewT : public CView,public CMyTemplateClassT<TYPE>
{
DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMyViewT<TYPE>)

private:
   CMyViewT();
'
'
'
}


IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMyViewT<TYPE>, CView)
```

Now I'm guessing the MFC macros are going to get upset by the templates, and am considering removing the dynamic creation macros for this class, and re-introducing it for each specialization of the template.  For example

```
template<class TYPE>
class CMytViewT : public CView,public CMyTemplateClassT<TYPE>
{
public:
   CMyViewT();
'
'
'
}

Class CMyView : public CMyViewT<CMyClass>
{
DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMyView)

private:
   CMyView();
}   

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMyView, CView)
```

I'm wondering is this going to cause problems going forward, as any other implementations I've seen have the macros included for all intermediate classes.  I can't see that it should, but have I missed something?

**Edit**  After looking at Matthew Holders answer below, I found the following [microsoft connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/161025/implement-dynamic-t-mfc-macro-for-c-templates-does-not-compile), which states that support for IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_T has been removed due to being buggy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, on the template use `IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE_T(CMyViewT, {specialization}, CView)` for each specialization if you want to support `DECLARE_DYNCREATE` and remove the `<TYPE>` from `DECLARE_DYNCREATE`.

Second, the only issue you may run into by not using DECLARE_* is using the MFC `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` macro to down-cast to or from CMyViewT; for which the C++ `dynamic_cast` is preferred anyways.

If you do plan on making a derivation of the template for each specializations, you really don't need DECLARE_DYNCREATE on your template view, just on your derivative.

Comment: +1, though the following article suggests the IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE_T macro is buggy and unsupported.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/161025/implement-dynamic-t-mfc-macro-for-c-templates-does-not-compile

Comment: Due to the way it was designed to work, just making derivatives for the specializations of the template does appear to be the best option.